# IT is back again

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My suffix will look after, 
>   My prefix leaves a mark,
>   My infix will take you places, 
>  
>   You often find me when it's dark.

**What Am I?**

Comment: Okay, stuff [this meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag) — that was $5$ months ago, and Riley Riddles are still going on. Like myself, who else votes for a tag? DVL13 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: a tag could indeed be helpful in finding all of the same types of riddles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you be

> **SCARE**?

`My suffix will look after,`

> **CARE**.

`My prefix leaves a mark,`

> **SCAR**.

`My infix will take you places,`

> **CAR**.

`You often find me when it's dark.`

> Oooo... **scary** :P

---

**Title:**

`IT is back again`

> Even [Freddy got scared](http://horrorzone.ru/uploads/_pages2/61463/0.jpg) :D

Comment: and there you go, you found it.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Nice riddle! The title and the first line gave it away for me, but the riddle was really fun overall :D

Comment: thanks for the feedback, the clue on the hint was probably quite obvious.. trying to make sure there is one clear answer often makes it easy i guess :D

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yeah, I see what you mean. Most of my riddles are pretty long for this reason — the shorter they are, the less detail they comprise, and the more likely it is of being more broad; i.e., having more than one answer. But that is one of the key elements I love about Riley Riddles: they are short and sweet, the format's neat, and it has one answer — what a treat! :D